# What is the most repeated programme on British telly?

Tags: scheduling, most-appearances

Asked in The Guardian's [Notes & Queries](http://www.guardian.co.uk/theguardian/2012/dec/19/most-repeated-tv-episode):

> I notice Channel 4 is again screening the [Christmassy Ted](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cqL2bjeLdDo&oref=http://www.youtube.com/channel/SWkyWJHHHIxwM&has_verified=1&has_verified=1) episode of Father Ted. Which episode of a TV series (as opposed to one-offs such as The Snowman) has been screened most often on one of the five main TV channels?

The five main TV channels are the UK's BBC1, BBC2, ITV, Channel 4 and Channel 5. The answer doesn't necessarily need to be a Christmas special. I'm looking for some concrete basis to the answer rather than guesswork.

Answer (score 2):

I found a few things on the net about this.

[Last of the Summer Wine](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2305227/Last-Summer-Wine-repeated-TV-year-far-nearly-FIVE-HUNDRED-epsiodes-screened-months.html) is currently the most repeated show of since the beginning of 2013 in the UK (483 episodes shown).

The rest of the list is as follows:

- My Family - 233 repeats
- QI - One of only    two current shows on list 179 times
- Only Fools and Horses - Classic    repeated 161 times
- The Good Life - Starring Richard Briers, 132    repeats
- My Parents Are Aliens - ITV show repeated 157 times
- Have I    Got News for You - Ongoing show, 126 repeats
- The Upper Hand - Another    ITV series, 110 repeats
- 'Allo 'Allo - French-themed classic, repeated    108 times

[Dinner for One](http://www.multemusic.com/frequently-repeated-tv-programme/) however is the most repeated of all time the world over. Despite it being a British comedy sketch it's almost never shown here.

Comment: This is interesting but doesn't answer the question: what's the most repeated *single episode* of a television series? Perhaps it'll be an episode from your lists, particularly one that didn't have many series (so each episode has been shown more times).